# How to reduce size of Lambda Layers/workaround the size limit/reduce size of R packages?

Tags: r, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm running R on AWS Lambda. I've been making a layer for the packages that are used by the R script. Below are the packages:

```r
install.packages(c("magrittr", "lubridate", "dplyr", "readr", "tidyr",
                   "aws.s3", "readxl", "here", "stringr"), 
                 lib = '/opt/R/new_library/R/library/')
```

However the subsequent folder produced exceeds 250 mb which is the limit for Lambda.

Therefore, I'm wondering what my options are:

- From an R perspective is there any way of reducing the size of the installed packages? For example, the BH and stringi (which must be dependents) are over 150 mb in size
- From an AWS perspective, is there any workaround for this lambda size limit? Can I use EFS to help here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complicated but packages are not generally programmed to an installation size constraint (but see for example [what we said about the tinyverse](https://tinyverse.org) and some thoughts about dependencies in general).

Consider `data.table` which has no dependencies, whereas `dplyr` has many -- I am not saying you *must* rewrite your script but it is one *possible* approach.

I am also the maintainer of `BH` and yes, it has a big footprint.  Worse, we do not need at run-time (!!) so you could (very drastically) `rm -rf` its headers. You would not be able to *compile* anymore but the already build ones would run.

Lastly, and that is the main tip:  Consider binaries.  You have both RSPM and BSPM and I have written [a few blog posts and videos](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/code/r4) on the topic -- scroll down to see a few. I am a big fan and big user of the Rutter PPAs which give you the above (maybe with the `aws.s3` package) as binaries ready to install -- and BSPM makes it easy from `install.packages()`.

*Edit* So for argument's sake I fire up `rocker/r-bspm:20.04` and most package arrived as binaries:

```
root@b52f4e461ebd:/# du -csh /usr/lib/R/site-library/*
136K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/askpass
140K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/assertthat
147M    /usr/lib/R/site-library/BH
212K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/bspm
212K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/cellranger
580K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/cli
172K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/clipr
840K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/cpp11
272K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/crayon
320K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/curl
516K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/digest
2.0M    /usr/lib/R/site-library/dplyr
136K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/ellipsis
368K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/fansi
160K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/generics
312K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/glue
296K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/here
224K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/hms
824K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/httr
692K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/jsonlite
292K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/lifecycle
2.2M    /usr/lib/R/site-library/littler
1.7M    /usr/lib/R/site-library/lubridate
476K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/magrittr
140K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/mime
3.2M    /usr/lib/R/site-library/openssl
308K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/pillar
116K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/pkgconfig
120K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/prettyunits
208K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/progress
584K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/purrr
188K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/R6
10M     /usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp
1.5M    /usr/lib/R/site-library/readr
1.7M    /usr/lib/R/site-library/readxl
108K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/rematch
636K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/remotes
1.4M    /usr/lib/R/site-library/rlang
300K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/rprojroot
1.3M    /usr/lib/R/site-library/stringi
456K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/stringr
156K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/sys
1.7M    /usr/lib/R/site-library/tibble
1.5M    /usr/lib/R/site-library/tidyr
416K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/tidyselect
524K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/utf8
1.8M    /usr/lib/R/site-library/vctrs
472K    /usr/lib/R/site-library/xml2
188M    total
root@b52f4e461ebd:/#
```

So with the suggested 'post-installation surgery' on `BH` (which, again, is a *build* and not *runtime* dependency by R does not differentiate) you can get that down to less than 50mb.

It is complemented by what installed from source:

```
root@b52f4e461ebd:/# du -csh /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/*
144K    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/askpass
312K    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/aws.s3
168K    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/aws.signature
132K    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/base64enc
2.1M    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/curl
388K    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/docopt
832K    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/httr
696K    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/jsonlite
140K    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/mime
3.2M    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/openssl
160K    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/sys
472K    /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/xml2
8.6M    total
root@b52f4e461ebd:/#
```

(and several of these exist as binaries so I'd have look more closely why BSPM did not pick binaries).